# How to execute action without change current page in mvc3

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-events

I make product my favourite with Javascript yes no window. When click yes button, product gets my favourite and refresh background page. I have `MakeMyFavorite` action in the controller, but it return **same** result every call.

```
public ActionResult MakeMyFavorite( int id )
{
   ....
   return RedirectToAction( "Details", "Product", product );
}
```

and Javascript:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function confirmFavorite() {
        if (confirm("Are you sure make favorite?")) {
            document.location.reload(true);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } 
</script>
```

and link:

```
<a href="@Html.Action ( "MakeMyFavorite", "Product", new { id = item.ID } )" 
     onclick = "return confirmFavorite()"> Make Favorite </a>
```

I use  **Make Favorite** link in different places in the site (Details, Index and other views). When click link, product is favourite, page refresh, but always opens Details view.
I changed `ActionResult` with `void` in the controller, but never open, because, there is not return view.
How should I do, in different pages of site, when I click **Make Favorite** link, product is favourite, but background page not change? To stay current view. (Sorry for bad English)

Comment: do you want to navigate different view when your are confirming favorite?

Comment: No, I want to stay current view when I confirm favorite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

Make a JsonResult Action

Like

```
public JsonResult MakeMyFavorite(int id)
{
   ......
   string result = "favorite";
   return this.Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Make your anchor tag like

```
<a href="#" id="myfav" onclick="confirmFavorite(@item.id);">Favorite</a>
```

and your jquery for handling this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function confirmFavorite (id) {
        if(confirm("Are you sure make favorite?")) {
           var data = { "id": id };
           $.getJSON("/Product/MakeMyFavorite", data, function (data) {
               //check your data here what it is returning
               if($.trim(data)=="favorite")
               {
                //Do what you want to do.
               }
           });
        }
     }

</script>
```

Comment: I added  document.location.reload(true); to bottom of "//Do what you want to do." in javascript. Now, dialog opens, product is favorite, but, current page disappear. White page seems, on top of page is "favorite" string

Comment: Why you want to reload the current page, is it will change something on current page? If don't, no need to reload page. if yes,  then `location.reload()` will work itself.

Comment: I reload page, that is why, "Add favorite" text disappears from product.

Comment: can you post what you did with anchor tag `<a href="#" id="myfav" onclick="confirmFavorite(@item.id);">Favorite</a>`

Answer (score 1):

Pass in a value (true) when you want reload, (false or no param) when you don't:

```
<a href="@Html.Action ( "MakeMyFavorite", "Product", new { id = item.ID } )" 
 onclick = "return confirmFavorite( true )"> Make Favorite </a>

<a href="@Html.Action ( "MakeMyFavorite", "Product", new { id = item.ID } )" 
 onclick = "return confirmFavorite( false )"> Make Favorite </a>
```

then in the js:

```
function confirmFavorite( reload ) {
    if (confirm("Are you sure make favorite?")) {
        if( reload ) {
            document.location.reload(true);
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: When MakeMyFavorite action works, Product/Details view loads. I want to stay in current page.

Comment: @Mores: By stay, you mean cancel the reload and do nothing?

Comment: Only reload current page and make favorite product.